# multidimentional array to if else statement in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, if-statement

hello first sorry for my bad english.

here i have some problem with PHP. how i can create / print (**if else**) statement from **ul** and **li** tag.

I have a multidimentional array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0, 'data' => '1.1');
    array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 0, 'data' => '1.2');
    array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 1, 'data' => '1.1.1');
    array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 1, 'data' => '1.1.2');
    array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 2, 'data' => '1.2.1');
    array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 2, 'data' => '1.2.2');
    array('id' => 7, 'parent' => 5, 'data' => '1.2.1.1');
    array('id' => 8, 'parent' => 5, 'data' => '1.2.1.2');
);
```

Then from the array above i need some code that should echo / print statement like this (**IN STRING FORMAT TO SAVE IN A VARIABLE**):

```
$str ='if (1.1) {
    if (1.1.1) {

    } else {

    }
} else {
    if (1.2.1) {
        if (1.2.1.1) {

        }
        else {

        }
    } else {

    }
}';
```

appreciate for your help... :)

Comment: wait i will post the array

Comment: @IvanBarayev i have update the data source... please help :)

Comment: @IvanBarayev manually, because still experimenting..

Comment: @IvanBarayev can not wait to give a check sign

Comment: @IvanBarayev just a reward for helpfull person

Comment: @IvanBarayev yep.. but i think you miss what i mean

Comment: Who are you? EGO is not good for people..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make condition with variable like this:

```
if ($val == "1.1") {
  //do the child if
}
```

PHP will not execute this:

```
if (1.1) {
}
```

Comment: hello, please check again i have update the data source.. please help :)

Answer (score 0):

First Step, make new array that's containing child node with key from parent id..

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
    $new_arr[$a['parent']][] = $a;
}
```

After that, you can access new_array with recursively function..

```
function rec_child($arr){
    global $new_arr;
    foreach($arr as $a){
        echo "<li>".$a['data']."</li>";
        if(!empty($new_arr[$a['id']])){         
            echo "<ul>";
            rec_child($new_arr[$a['id']]);
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "";
    }
}
```

So, call rec_child function like this..

```
echo "<ul>";
rec_child($new_arr[0]);
echo "</ul>";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i think you miss what i mean